# What do I call software as opposed to DB/DBMS?

Tags: terminology, programming, software

In my documentation I'm trying to refer to the program in context of interaction with database / DBMS as opposed to the latter. How do I call such program or software? "Outbound", "outer", "calling", "querying"? E. g. "IDs are explicitly stored in table xyz and their proper incrementation/decrementation is a responsibility of `<???>` software".

Comment: Unclear.  Are you talking about the client of the DBMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would normally use "the application layer":

> IDs are explicitly stored in table xyz and their proper incrementation/decrementation is a responsibility of the application layer.

Answer (score 2):

You could use ['Client'](http://techterms.com/definition/client)

> ... if an office has a server that stores the company's database on it, the other computers in the office that can access the database are "clients" of the server.
>
> *techterms.com*